# Oracle SQL: What happens when you UPDATE a nonexistent record?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

```
  UPDATE CONTACTS_TABLE SET CONTACT_DETAILS = 'email@site.ph'
  WHERE CONTACT_TYPE = 'CTT04'
  AND PIN = '1234543210';
```

If no record with the given **CONTACT_TYPE** and **PIN** exists, will a new one with the given **CONTACT_TYPE**, **PIN** and **CONTACT_DETAILS** be created instead, or will there be an error?

Comment: What exactly is your requirement? If there are no records which match the update, would you want that record to be inserted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0 rows will get updated. There won't be any new entry with this 'UPDATE' statement.There won't be any error message too.

Answer (score 1):

0 rows updated.

CONTACT_TYPE, PIN and CONTACT_DETAILS wont change, or it does not give any error

you can read this [document](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.2.1/ref/rrefsqlj26498.html) and [this](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/update.php)